# Is there a way to reorganize what slots bitizens are working in?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

For example, my Jedi Jump Up has a level 9 dream job in the 1st slot, an 8 dream job in the 2nd and a 5 dream job in the last and most valuable slot. Or similarly, My Trianing Remotes has my one lvl 9 dream job in the first slot and the other slots are filled with regular lvl 9's but it would make sense to have the dream job 9's in the last slot(s) for double of the highest priced items.

I've tried firing the entire staff and re-hiring in different orders but TDS puts them back in the same slots. Does TDS determine what slots bitizens works?

Answer (score 2):

You can't reorganize them in any meaningful way, sadly, but it might make less difference than you think.

The levels of the bitizens on the floor are summed together, so it doesn't matter which slot is filled by who in this regard.  The total level of all the bitizens gives you a percentage discount on the stock time for all items on the floor.

Thus, if your bitizen order is 9 in the first, 0 in the second, and 9 in the third, it is the same as having 9 in the first two and 0 in the third, or any other possible order of the bitizens.

For dream jobs, the first dream job worker on the floor will *always* double the stock of the first item, regardless of where they are actually "working" according to the status of the floor.

Thus, if your first bitizen is working their dream job, they'll double the first good.  But if you only have one dream job worker on a floor and they're in the third slot, they'll *still* double the first good.

Comment: I agree with everything except for the pooled skills. Are you sure that's true?  I've not seen anywhere that showed this to be true. I'm willing to believe it, but can you show an example with photos or something?

Comment: Just look at the store info.  It gives you a total rank # for the whole store.  It does that because that's the number it cares about.

Comment: @DavidM, I took screenshots but can't upload from here.  On one of my floors with 3 workers, I fired the level 9 guy in the middle, which took my stock time of the middle good from 49 minutes to 54 minutes.  I then hired him again (which put him in the bottom slot) and it took the stock time back down to 49 minutes again.

Comment: You should be able to test this yourself on any floor that isn't currently stocking, with stock times long enough that you can tell the difference.  Just fire someone who isn't in the bottom slot and then hire them back, keeping track of your stock times.

Comment: Agent86, thanks for your answer!  I hadn't noticed the effect before, but it seems to be true.

Comment: The OP probably wants to double the bottom spot first as to maximize its number of items for sale. But the only way to do that is to get 3 dream jobbers into the shop.